# Machine learning size of input and output

Tags: python, machine-learning

At the moment I'm playing around with machine learning in python based on [this website](http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/) (part two is about image recognition) . I would like to train a network to recognize 4 specific points in am image but My problem is:

The neural network is created by simply multiplying matrices together, calculate the delta between the given output and the recognized output and recalculate the weights in the matrix. Now let' say I have a `600x800` pixel image as input. If I multiply this with my layer matrices I can't get a `4x2` matrix as output (`x,y` for each point).

My second problem is how much hidden layers should I have for this problem? Are more layers always better but need longer to calculate? Can we guess how much hidden layers we need or should we test some values and use the best of it?

**My current neural network code:**

```
from os.path import isfile
import numpy as np

class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self):
        np.random.seed(1)
        self.syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((480000,8)) - 1

    @staticmethod
    def relu(x, deriv=False):
        if(deriv): 
            res = np.maximum(x, 0)
            return np.minimum(res, 1)
        return np.maximum(x, 0)

    def train(self, imgIn, out):
        l1 = NeuralNetwork.relu(np.dot(imgIn, self.syn0))

        l1_error = out - l1

        exp = NeuralNetwork.relu(l1,True)
        l1_delta = l1_error * exp

        self.syn0 += np.dot(imgIn.T,l1_delta)
        return l1 #np.abs(out - l1)

    def identify(self, img):
        return NeuralNetwork.relu(np.dot(imgIn, self.syn0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1. Input data.

You must serialize the input. For example, if you have one 600*800 pixel image, input must be 1*480000(rows, cols). 
Row means the number of data and column means the dimension of data.

Problem 2. Classification.

If you want to classify 4 different type of classes, you should use (1,4) vector for output. For example, there are 4 classes ('Fish', 'Cat', 'Tiger', 'Car'). Then vector (1,0,0,0) means Fish.

Problem 3. Fully connected network.

I think the example in this homepage uses fully connected network. It uses whole image for classifying once. If you want to classify with subset of image. You should use convolution neural network or other approach. I don't know well about this.

Problem 4. Hyperparameter

It depends on data. you must test with various hyper parameter. then choose best hyper parameter.

Comment: Okay that helped me. Thank you! But now I'm facing another problem: When I multiply my image with my first layer (at the beginning random generated) the values in the result matrix are so big that the `exp` function from the nonlin (sigmoid) method can not be calculated. Any ideas who I can proximate that? Or is there maybe a better sigmoid function?

Comment: you can use Relu function. The sigmoid function is not used currently because they have gradient vanishing problem. ReLU is best solution for almost every situation

Comment: Okay thank you I will try it with this! Do I also use the derivative of this function to calculate the `error_delta` because it is only `0` or `1` which looks a bit strange to me.

Comment: Yes. you have to. There are some modified version of ReLU, but I think simple ReLU fits well.

Comment: I tried with the new Relu function but this always return 0 vectors to me. I added my code from the neural network to the question. Would be great if you can have a look on it.

Comment: BTW my image is in grayscale so I have one channel with values from 0 to 255 and my expected output are the coordinates between 800 and 600. Do I have to normalize these values between 0 and 1?

Comment: You must get mean, stddev for training set. Then apply it to normalize training, test set.

Comment: Okay so I do not have to change the image itself but my expected output right? Let's say my two features are rotation and the position of the points. So I should devide the angle by 2Pi and the position by the width and height of the image to get both between 0 and 1. Would that be enough?